# Is there an equivalent of leaps() or stepAIC() for GAM in R?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

Quite straight-forward, looking for a function that can mass-search combination of predictors for GAMs.

The function leaps() does so for normal linear regression, it returns the best model at every number of predictors (at 3 predictors, at 4 predictors, etc).

The function stepAIC allows us to specify a floor (predictors that have to be included), a ceiling (largest model that you allow), and searches for a model in between, stepwise (adding or removing one predictor at a time).

However I'm unaware of any function that can do this for GAM, from the two classes I follow we had to manually construct 10+ models, severely limiting the number of models we can search.

Answer (score 0):

So there is `step.gam`, see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/gam/man/step.gam.html). The syntax, as far as I can tell, is the same as stepAIC. This is still not as ideal as a hypothetical `leaps.gam` that searches exhaustively, but this still is an immense help.